# Problema com leitura de arquivos em python

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash

Qual é a diferença entre, fazer o python abrir e ler um arquivo, de passar o resultado da leitura entre áspas?

Pois quando abro um arquivo, que contem apenas a palavra **teste** e passo esse resultado da leitura por um algoritmo de hash o resultado é:

> cf83e1357eefb8bdf1542850d66d8007d620e4050b5715dc83f4a921d36ce9ce47d0d13c5d85f2b0ff8318d2877eec2f63b931bd47417a81a538327af927da3e

Obs: Resultado não é o esperado

Agora se passo como parâmetro dentro do código(não é input de usuário) para o algoritmo de hash a string **"teste"**

> b123e9e19d217169b981a61188920f9d28638709a5132201684d792b9264271b7f09157ed4321b1c097f7a4abecfc0977d40a7ee599c845883bd1074ca23c4af

Obs: Esse é o resultado esperado; estou usando o **.encode('utf-8')** no comando

Comando:

```
hashlib.sha512(hash_target).hexdigest()
```

No qual **hash_target** é a string que vai passar pelo algoritmo de hash, que no exemplo acima seria a string **teste**

Para ler o arquivo usei o comando:

```
archive = open(file, 'r')
```

Comment: Como fez para ler o arquivo?

Comment: E por acaso não restou um `\n` no final da linha lida do arquivo?

Comment: fiz o teste com o '\n' passando pelo algoritmo, junto a "teste"(como fiz na segunda tentativa, também mostrada na pergunta), ou seja "teste\n", e deu em um resultado diferente mesmo do primeiro mostrado na pergunta, ou seja teoricamente não.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Após ler o arquivo vc precisa extrair o conteúdo dele (com readlines, por exemplo), antes disso a variável é um `text.IOwrapper` e não uma string.

Veja:

```
str1 = open(file, 'r')
str2 = 'teste'

type(str1)
_io.TextIOWrapper

type(str2)
str

str1==str2
False
```

Agora veja dessa outra forma:

```
string1 = open(file,'r').readlines()[0].rstrip()
string2 = 'teste'
string1==string2
True
```